# AngularJS > Bootstrap UI > Editing Item in Modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on a project that makes sense to add and edit items within a modal window. The add portion is working fine. The edit portion is opening the modal but my ng-model is not reflecting and the input fields are blank within the modal window.

Here's a plunker to illustrate the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/8mHOo0YE4qv0UcDvCCgS?p=preview

AngularJS Code:

```
// Code goes here
var userPopup = angular.module('userPopup', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
userPopup.controller('popupController', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
$scope.users = [{
    name: 'Steve',
    job: 'Accounting',
    age: '39',
    sal: '36000',
    addr: '123 Streetly Unit 2, Chicago, IL 60601'
 }];

$scope.editUser = function(user) {
    var dialogInst = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'edit.html',
      controller: 'editDialogInstCtrl',
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        selectedUser: function() {
          return $scope.user;
        }
      }
    });

  };

  $scope.addUser = function() {
    var dialogInst = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'popup.html',
      controller: 'DialogInstCtrl',
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        selectedUser: function() {
          return $scope.user;
        }
      }
    });

    dialogInst.result.then(function(newuser) {
      $scope.users.push(newuser);
      $scope.user = {
        name: '',
        job: '',
        age: '',
        sal: '',
        addr: ''
      };
    }, function() {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

userPopup.controller('DialogInstCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, selectedUser, $log) {
  //Assign Selected User
  $scope.user = selectedUser;

  $scope.submitUser = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.user);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});

userPopup.controller('editDialogInstCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, selectedUser, $log) {
  //Assign Selected User
  $scope.user = selectedUser;

  $scope.save = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.user);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="editUser(selectedUser)">Edit</a>
```

I know it's close and I'm overlooking something. Please advise.

thank you

Comment: I'd guess that `resolve: {
        selectedUser: function() {
          return $scope.user;
        }
      }` should be `resolve: {
        selectedUser: function() {
          return user;
        }
      }`  you have a parameter but you aren't using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **two** issues, that are just typos, really.

#### In your JS code:

```
//                  passing `user` here
//                          v
$scope.editUser = function(user) {
  var dialogInst = $uibModal.open({
    /* ... */
    resolve: {
      selectedUser: function() {
        return $scope.user;
      } //          ^
    }   // using $scope.user there
  });
};
```

You're passing an argument to the `editUser` function, but not actually using it; referring instead to `$scope.user`, which is `undefined`.
It should be: `selectedUser: function() { return user; }`

#### In your HTML template:

```
<!-- declaring `user` here -->
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.job}}</td>
    <td>{{user.age}}</td>
    <td>{{user.sal | currency}}</td>
    <td>{{user.addr}}</td>
                                       <!-- using `selectedUser` there -->
    <td><a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="editUser(selectedUser)">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

You're iterating over `users`, using a `user` variable; then referring to a (non-existent) `selectedUser` when calling `editUser`.
It should be: `<a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="editUser(user)">Edit</a>`

---

Here's a link to [a (working) fork of your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DqVCye?p=preview).

Comment: I've had the darnedest time with this one! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this code in your view.
replace this code

```
<td><a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="editUser(selectedUser)">Edit</a></td>
```

to

```
<td><a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="editUser(user)">Edit</a></td>
```

and in your controller when invoke the modal.. change

```
$scope.editUser = function(user) {
var dialogInst = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'edit.html',
  controller: 'editDialogInstCtrl',
  size: 'lg',
  resolve: {
    selectedUser: function() {
      return $scope.user;
    }
  }
});
};
```

to

```
$scope.editUser = function(user) {
var dialogInst = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'edit.html',
  controller: 'editDialogInstCtrl',
  size: 'lg',
  resolve: {
    selectedUser: function() {
      return user;
    }
  }
});
};
```

Comment: Didn't realize $scope is no longer needed in modal instance. Thanks for pointing out @jesus-carrasco